# helm-maven-plugin (kiwigrid or deviceinsight)?

Tags: maven, kubernetes-helm, fabric8

I am looking for a maven plugin to build, package and publish my helm package. I have come across two - what seems to be identical plugins:

https://github.com/kiwigrid/helm-maven-plugin

https://github.com/deviceinsight/helm-maven-plugin

It seems that:

https://github.com/kiwigrid/helm-maven-plugin

has the most users, but why are the two identical plugins for the same thing??

Also seems fabric8.io comes with helm packaging support:

https://fabric8.io/guide/mavenFabric8Helm.html

Or is that no longer the goto project for maven/k8s build/deploy integration?

Also in case this kind of tools comparison/recommendation does not belong here in stackoverflow is there another "stackexchange" where these types of questions are better suited?

Comment: They do not seem identical.

Comment: No not 100% identical but provides the same functionality, build, package and publish helm charts. E.g. I would expect that you would not combine both plugins in the same build but instead have to choose between one of the two

Comment: You can create Helm charts using JKube's Kubernetes-maven-plugin or OpenShift-maven-plugin (https://www.eclipse.org/jkube/docs/kubernetes-maven-plugin#jkube:helm) which are the evolution of Fabric8 Maven Plugin.
JKube doesn't publish the charts, but I'm sure if you open an issue requesting the feature, it will be considered.